# jquery submit handler with jquery validate and jquery ajax form only gets called every second time

Tags: jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I have the following code

```
jQuery(function() {
      jQuery("#newForm").validate({
          rules: { },
          submitHandler: function(form) {
              alert("Submitting")
              jQuery("#submitButton").attr('disabled', true)
              jQuery("#sendWrapper").append('<span><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/loading.gif"></span>')
              jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
                  success: afterFormSubmit,
                  target: "#ajaxwrapper"
              });
          }
      });
});
```

I'm finding that the handler is only getting called every first, third, fifth, 7th time the submit button is clicked (the response is pretty much just the form's html with errors etc inserted).

However, changing the function to an onclick handler works everytime.

Answer (score 2):

This should works fine:

```
jQuery(function() {
      jQuery("#newForm").validate({
          rules: {},
          submitHandler: function(form) {
              alert("Submitting")
              jQuery("#submitButton").attr('disabled', true)
              jQuery("#sendWrapper").append('<span><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/loading.gif"></span>')
              $.ajax({
                  cache: false,
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: ("#newForm").serialize(),
                  url : '/ your-url-address-to-post-form /'
                  success: function (html) {
                      alert('done');
                  },
                  error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                      alert('error')
                  }
              });
          }
      });
});​
```

Comment: Is there a reason why my code doesn't work? (I'm more interested in the jquery theory behind what's happening than getting it working :S))

Comment: I'm with @Taras. Your answer, if explained, might help people with similar (but not exactly the same) problem.